# Recommendation of a combination of Graph DBs/Language

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j

I'm starting a new project that will rely on social network graphs.

I looked on Neo4j.rb. Because of the lack of full ActiveRecord compatibility, I have to review code that should just work.

Trying to use the basics described in [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/), I am stuck on missing methods `find_by_provider_and_uid`, while using Devise requires a fork to work with Neo4j.rb.

Other alternatives each has it issues. For example:

- Neography get's me writing Cypher syntax
- Pacer has almost no documentation

Has anyone built a purely neo4j/orientDB project that implements modular authentication (OpenID, Twitter and Facebook)?

If so, what framework and language would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Max De Marzi deployed a number of applications on heroku using Facebook and twitter APIs (and also OpenAuth). See http://maxdemarzi.com

And cypher is the way to go for the future, there is also a framework on top of neography called neoid that adds Rails support. (https://github.com/elado/neoid)

Neo4j.rb is for embedded deployment, i.e. you run Neo4j within your webapp.

Comment: From what I understand NeoID would require me two different databases. One for its ActiveRecord Base and the other for neo4j data (neoidable part of the model)?